# How can I locate where in a JSON file a key is located?

Tags: python, json, file

I'm writing a parser that uses a JSON file for configuration, and if it detects an invalid value, I want to be able to output the location of the problematic data in the form of the **line and column number in the source file** where the error occurred. I've set up all of the tracing and have a path to the problematic data in the form of a list, where each item is either a key to an object or an array index, like `["foo", "bar", 3, "baz"]`, but can't figure out how to locate where in the file the path is.

Ideally, the error handling code should be able to print this:

```
ValidationError: Features require a "feature"
  at .features[0]: "theme.json" line 6, column 13
```

I found that using a custom `JSONDecoder` lets you hook into the processing of objects through `JSONDecoder.object_hook` but the information given to that function is not sufficient and there isn't any hook for arrays, either.

If needed, this is the error class:

```py
class JSONTraceable(Exception):
    def __init__(
        self,
        message: str,
        json_path: typing.Union[str, typing.List[typing.Union[str, int]]] = "",
    ):
        super().__init__(message)
        if isinstance(json_path, str):
            self.json_path = [json_path]
        elif isinstance(json_path, list):
            self.json_path = json_path
        else:
            raise TypeError(
                f"JSON path should be a string or a list, not {type(json_path).__name__}"
            )

    def extend(self, key: typing.Union[str, int]):
        self.json_path.insert(0, key)
```

Comment: What does json column mean?

Comment: @СергейКох I've edited the question to improve its clarity, but I was using the word 'column' to describe how far to the right on a line the error occurred. (column 1 is the first character, 2 is the second character, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by writing my own JSON parser that keeps track of the location of everything as it runs, following the spec available at [json.org](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). If you want to have a look at the full code for the parser, it's on GitHub: [github permalink](https://github.com/penguinencounter/pixelscribe/blob/91c2d14b264a811abed81d9d95eb9df3f395dd27/pixelscribe/parser/reader.py)